# how to sort a list of lists of items bases on the total sum of some item's attrinutes in LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

The problems is I have a `class A` which has an attribute `Count` of `int`. Then there is B which is a List of Lists of `A`(`List<List<A>>`). Now I want to sort B based on the sum of Count ranging over all elements of `A` in each sublist in `B`. How should I write this in linq.

```
B.OrderBy(element => (how can I sum the Count for each A here)).ToList()
```

Comment: Do you mean something looks like this: `B.OrderBy(element => element.Sum(subElement => subElement.Count)).ToList();`?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria does it do sum of all `A` is each sublist of `B`? If so would you please explain to me a bit

Comment: @cloudcrypt explains it into the answer. So just check it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
B.OrderBy(element => element.Sum(a => a.Count)).ToList();
```

What's happening here is that for each sublist `List<A>` of `B`, a sum of the `Count` attribute of each `A` object is being computed. B is then ordered by that sum.